# Cloning options for workstations

Tags: cloning

So far I have not used cloning as an option for new computers, but now I have a problem because i need to install about 50 computers with the same setting and installed programs.

How do you troubleshoot a computer name after cloning, SID changing, diferent hardware etc..
Nevermind if its xp, vista, 7, 8 or linux... Wich metods are you guys use for stuffs like this ?

sory for bad english if it is

Answer (score 9):

Windows Deployment Services. This will address all of your concerns regarding hostname, SID, etc.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831764.aspx

(There are other options, such as Altiris Deployment Solution, and others, but WDS should get you started on a path.)

Comment: That will not use definitly, cooust to much money and licence for server etc. and i will use cloning this time its spending money.
What do u use for cloning @danbig?

Comment: Reliable and functional cloning or imaging solutions are not likely to be cheap.

Comment: I say you must be joking for bringin wds in talk, its spending money for nothing  or something but wds zomg, acronis could make things good.

Comment: @sergio: Your time is money.

Comment: Well what money? 50 computers and no active directory is a ouch in itself. As in - not professional. Voting to close.

Comment: Not sure what your problem with this suggestion is. WDS is a free role built into Windows Server.

Answer (score 2):

> Nevermind if its xp, vista, 7, 8 or linux...

No, this **DOES** matter. If you're deploying linux, you're stuck with the abomination known as clonezilla, which has serious limitations.

See: http://mdtguy.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/clonezilla-is-a-joke-and-a-bad-one-at-that/

If you're deploying Win 7/8 you're in luck because you can use Microsoft's free tools to deploy, no need for a server, MDT lite touch can be hosted from any Windows 7 system. If WDS really is out of the question, then you would just use MDT to build the WinPE boot media for you.

> computer name after cloning, SID changing, diferent hardware etc

Computer name can be dealt with using MDT lite touch, you would use a variable to assign names with serial numbers, location, or even formfactor.

If the reference image is built and sysprepped in a VM, its hardware agnostic,

If you organize drivers in MDT in make/model hirearchies you can use the driver group variables to point them at the right folders based on the %Make% %Model% Variables detected by WMI at boot in WinPE.

MDT lite touch will build the images for you, and then you can roll out those images with MDT again.

Use The Microsoft Deployment Toolkit. WDS is optional, as its really only needed for PXE boot and multicasting. If you're looking for a FREE solution, it's hard to beat Microsoft's Deployment Toolkit, which is series of consoles and scripts to manage and automate the Windows Assesment and Deployment Toolkit.

While Alteris is a decent product, many of the features of MDT make it a somewhat outdated product.

Key benefits of MDT lite touch:

- **Speed up deployments**- MDT is fast, It can image a
  system in 10min flat.
- **Improve standardization** -
  Reducing Image count allows you to standardize the environment you
  support.
- **Automate deployments** - Tedious and
  monotonous tasks are easily automated with MDT
- **Reduce
  Costs** - MDT is free, and since it saves you time, it saves
  you money.
- **Scalable deployments** - Start small, and
  take it to the next level with a deployment database down the road.
  or WDS integration.

But more than just imaging, MDT does more...

It names workstations, installs software on the fly for you (reducing image count) joins to the domain for you, (and it's free). http://mdtguy.wordpress.com/what-is-mdt/

Answer (score 0):

Want it cheap? What you're not paying on products/solutions is definitely gonna cost you more time.  Here are some solutions I used in the past.

- Sysprep + cloning
- dd/CloneZilla/PING + newsid.exe
- Automated USB drive deployment with WinPE, sysprep/WAIK and lots of testing + planning

Changing hardware will result in a different image usually.
Changing already deployed software will result in a different image usually.
Changing Windows version will result in a different image usually...

so much factors.